# How can P2V windows server 2008?

Tags: vmware, esxi, p2v

I am trying, to converter a windows server 2008 32 bits to virtual with
***vmware vcenter converter standalone*** but the application dosent start

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyMaX.png) 
im running Windows server 2008 32 bits wwhitn online conecction

Comment: You need to start the `VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Server` service.  If you encounter an error performing that task, you need to provide the vital information, required to solve that problem otherwise it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using a the app  [starwind](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter) to convert the physical server to virtual